# Capture still image from AVCaptureSession in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession

I have an `AVCaptureSession` that displays live video in a UIView, and I want to save a frame of the video stream as a UIImage. I've been dissecting the code I keep seeing around the internet, but I'm having trouble with the first line:

```
if let stillOutput = self.stillImageOutput {
    // Establish an AVCaptureConnection and capture a still image from it.
}
```

This gives me the error **'Camera' does not have a member named 'stillImageOutput'.** The code depends on being able to get the video connection from the output.

I can post the full code block if that'd be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the full code?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have `stillImageOutput` you can use following methods to capture image

```
 stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]
    if captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
        captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
    }

    // I had to add timer otherwise quality was messed up in iPad
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("getImage"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Than my function to get image

```
func getImage() {

    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
        stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection) {
            (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
            let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)

//          Use your image or store to Album

//          UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage(data: imageData), nil, nil, nil)
            self.stopSession()

        }
    }

}
```

And to stop session and remove preview layer

```
func stopSession(){


    self.captureSession.stopRunning()
    self.previewLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()

}
```