# Fetch Video Detail From HTTP Live Streaming using AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently working on HTTP Live streaming video with AVPlayerViewController / AVPlayer

i am play a video with .m38u file supported

It playing fine but my question is that can i have the data of video like i have set 4 type of resolution while genrating the .m38u file.. , i can varies the resoltion at my end point now the question is how to get the all values which i have setup at my endpoint.  I am play this is in android also and using Track i am able to fetch all the video information but in ios how can i fetch all the details containing the video like its height , with, track,resolution supported by video etc..

I have search alot but could not get succeed..
Need help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello Anita. I have read your question. I have similar question and want to implement same thing as you described. So did u get any solution for it ? If so then please help me to solve

Comment: i face same problem have any solution @Anita ???

Answer (score 0):

Anita, I start I hope here is slice of code for playing a VIDEO..

```
self.command.text = "Loading VIDEO"


            let videoURL = self.currentSlide.aURL
            self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: videoURL)
            self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem)
            self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
            self.streamPlayer =  AVPlayerViewController()
            self.streamPlayer.player = self.player
            self.streamPlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 128, y: 222, width: 512, height: 256)

            let currentFM = self.streamPlayer.player?.currentItem?.asset
            for blah in (currentFM?.metadata.enumerate())! {
                print("blah \(blah)")
            }

            self.presentViewController(self.streamPlayer, animated: true)
                self.streamPlayer.player!.play()
            }
```

I added a little extra for showing meta data about the video... it printed...

```
blah (0, <AVMetadataItem: 0x15e7e4280, identifier=itsk/gsst, keySpace=itsk,     key class = __NSCFNumber, key=gsst, commonKey=(null), extendedLanguageTag=   (null), dataType=com.apple.metadata.datatype.UTF-8, time={INVALID}, duration=    {INVALID}, startDate=(null), extras={
dataType = 1;
dataTypeNamespace = "com.apple.itunes";
}, value=0>)
blah (1, <AVMetadataItem: 0x15e7e1a50, identifier=itsk/gstd, keySpace=itsk, key class = __NSCFNumber, key=gstd, commonKey=(null), extendedLanguageTag=(null), dataType=com.apple.metadata.datatype.UTF-8, time={INVALID}, duration={INVALID}, startDate=(null), extras={
dataType = 1;
dataTypeNamespace = "com.apple.itunes";
}, value=222980>)
```

Hopefully it means a lot more to you than it does to me :) What your looking I think is classed/called metadata in Applespeak...

Take a look at this post too

[Capture still image from AVCaptureSession in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26529787/capture-still-image-from-avcapturesession-in-swift)

It describes how-to capture a frame of your video, once you have a frame you can take a closer look at its meta data and I suspect find out some of the details you seek.

let metadata = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata] as? NSDictionary
let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

Are the commands to try and fetch that... let me know if you manage to succeed!

Comment: How can i fetch the resolution data which we can  shown in youTube player like "Auto","160","240","360" etc or how can we achieve this kind of functionality for selection view video in diff resolution

Comment: Sorry i am not getting you enough but still thank you for your help...https://www.hlsplayer.net/  : this is the link for play m3s8 files online when u pass the file name  it will give you option at bottom like HD (auto,160,240,360) etc... i want to develop my video diito as developed at this url given by me... can you please pass me code to acheve similer kind of functionality at my endpoint in swift..